# Is $dirty, $pristine in AngularJS be used in forms only?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am new to AngularJs and I know that I can use **$dirty , $pristine, $ error** in form validation. However is it necessary to explicitly create a form in

> `<form>..</form>`

to use these properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it necessary to explicitly create a form

The answer to that is no.

While using a `form` tag is very helpful for creating sets of input tags to process as a whole (usually by sending to a server) it is not necessary for angular's purposes.

You can easily use the `ng-form` directive as an attribute on other tag types (not just form).

From the source code you can see that if you are using the `form` tag or `ng-form` as **E**lement, **A**ttribute or **C**lass you will get the same behavior

```
restrict: isNgForm ? 'EAC' : 'E'
```

[link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L455)

Answer (score 3):

Hi since you are new to Angualar js nothing is better to start from the maker itself. As Sathish said AngularJsDocumentation is very good.
To answer your question is Yes you have to create a form explicitly because these are the properties of the form.
To understand the form better you can go to this link http://mrbool.com/the-concepts-of-angularjs-forms/29117